# PowerShell function ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName not using alias parameter name

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, alias

Trying to create a function that takes objects on the pipeline using the alias property. I'm not sure where this is going wrong.

Example of the process:

```
function Get-Name
{
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [alias("givenname")]
    [System.String] $FirstName,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [alias("sn")]
    [System.String] $LastName
  )
  write-host "firstName = $FirstName / $($FirstName.GetType().FullName)"
  Write-host "LastName  = $LastName  / $($LastName.GetType().FullName)"
}
```

If I run this command:

```
Get-Aduser -filter {sn -eq 'smith'} -properties sn,givenname | Get-Name
```

the output looks like this:

```
firstName =  / string
LastName  =   / string
```

The Function never seems to grab the sn and givenname attributes from the passed in object. What am I missing?

Comment: To be a bit more clear, I want the ADuser object to be passed to the Get-Name function which picks up the 'givenname' property as the firstname parameter and the 'sn' value for the last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The AD Cmdlets are to blame here**

The problem here is that the AD Cmdlets return objects in really non-standard ways.  For instance, with any other cmdlet if you take the output of the command and select a non-existing property, you'll get back nothing, like this:

```
get-date | select Hamster

Hamster                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-------     

>
```

See, nothing.  Sure, it says Hamster, but there is no actual Object there.  This is standard PowerShell behavior.

Now, look at what Get-ADUser does instead:

```
get-aduser -Filter {sn -eq 'adkison'} | select Hamster

Hamster                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-------                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
{}
```

It creates a $null!  So what will happen with your function is that PowerShell will look for a property of -LastName or -FirstName, get a $null and then stop right there.  It sucks!

The best way around this is to swap the parameter names like this, and it will still work:

```
function Get-Name
{
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [alias('FirstName')]
    [System.String] $givenname,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [alias("sn","lastname")]
    [System.String] $Surname
  )
  write-host "firstName = $givenname / $($givenname.GetType().FullName)"
  Write-host "LastName  = $SurName  / $($SurName.GetType().FullName)"
}


get-aduser -Filter {sn -eq 'adkison'} | Get-Name

firstName = James / System.String
LastName  = Adkison  / System.String
```

## Want to know more?

Check out [this awesome answer from /u/JBSmith on the topic.](https://serverfault.com/questions/630920/pipeline-input-to-functions-write-progress-and-alias)

Comment: Interesting! Odd that it doesn't even try the alias! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The statement "The best way around this is to swap the parameter names like this, and it will still work:" is incorrect in that swapping has nothing to do with this working.  The reason why this code works is because the parameters in the custom function now exactly match the output, whereby bypassing Alias all together.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've been able to determine, it isn't technically the AD cmdlets that are to blame, but the types in the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management` namespace--in this case, `ADUser`. The properties on `ADUser` are ultimately all just stored in a private `SortedDictionary` and fetched through get accessors, which might explain why it doesn't work quite as expected.

As alluded to by Colyn1337 in a previous comment, `ADUser` doesn't contain a property (or key) named either `sn` or `LastName` by default, so you'd need to either include an alias of `Surname` on your `LastName` parameter or select `sn` in your `Get-ADUser` call:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {sn -eq 'Adkison'} -Properties sn | Get-Name
```

That still won't work, but from there you can just pipe to `Select-Object` before piping to your function:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {sn -eq 'Adkison'} -Properties sn | Select * | Get-Name
```

Of course, you could also just select the specific properties you need instead of * in `Select-Object`. I assume this works because it resolves the `ADUser` dictionary into a `PSCustomObject` with concrete properties. Once resolved, they will match aliases as well as the actual parameter names.