# Why does Add-Member think every possible property already exists (on a Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser object)?

Tags: powershell

So, I was helping out in an [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/726346/how-can-i-export-to-csv-a-custom-output-along-with-module-properties-powershel/726357?noredirect=1#comment904801_726357) and I ran into some odd behaviour.

If I get an object of the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` type, such as through `Get-ADUser`, whenever I try to add a `NoteProperty` using `Add-Member`, you get the following situation:

```
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u = get-aduser someuser
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u | add-member ldskfjlkdsfj dfklsjdflkdsjf
add-member : Cannot add a member with the name "ldskfjlkdsfj" because a member with that
name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to your
command.
At line:1 char:6
+ $u | add-member ldskfjlkdsfj dfklsjdflkdsjf
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=someuser,...example,DC=com:PSObject) [Add-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MemberAlreadyExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand
```

Using the `-Force` parameter does allow me to "overwrite" this bogus property, but what is it about this object that makes it act like it already has every property?

Trying to access any property (even one not previously added) just returns nothing, rather than throwing an exception as I'd expect. Setting a property is possible, although with a "regular" PowerShell object I imagine it shouldn't be.

```
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u = get-aduser someuser
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u.bogus
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u.fishy
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u.fishy = "fish"
PS C:\Users\someuser> $u.fishy
fish
PS C:\Users\someuser>
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but this behaviour is seen for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 with PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: I hesitated a bit about the question placement, on whether this belongs on ServerFault or StackOverflow, in the end I thought it belonged here because it's a general PowerShell programming question, and the original question was about how to use PowerShell to acheive a sysadmin task.

Comment: I think it belongs here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the AD objects are "special" and they act weirdly when it comes to the extended properties. You can [read more about that in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29928911/3905079), where it messes with pipeline binding.

In this case, I think is due to `Add-Member` testing for the existence of a specific property (which on an AD object will always be true even if the property is one you just made up and has no value).

You've seen this yourself when testing various property names and assigning to them.

You should be able to use `Add-Member -Force` to make it work though.