# Properties not showing correctly for ADUsers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I found something that was sort of odd while looking through ADUsers in Powershell.

If I typed the following:

```
PS> Get-ADUser Xuser -Properties PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate
```

I would get an output like this:

```
DistinguishedName : CN=Xuser,OU=Domain Users,DC=LocalDC,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : 
LastLogonDate     : 7/14/2016 8:24:03 AM
Name              : Xuser
ObjectClass       : user
PasswordLastSet   : 7/1/2016 11:48:37 AM
SamAccountName    : Xuser
Surname           :
UserPrincipalName :
```

As you can see, I have timestamps on PasswordLastSet and LastLogonDate.

However, if I type this following:

```
PS> $user = Get-ADUser Xuser
PS> $user.LastLogonDate -eq $null
PS> True
PS> $user.PasswordLastSet -eq $null
PS> True
```

To make sure nothing was messed up, I typed:

```
PS> $user

DistinguishedName : CN=Xuser,OU=Domain Users,DC=LocalDC,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : 
LastLogonDate     : 
Name              : Xuser
ObjectClass       : user
PasswordLastSet   : 
SamAccountName    : Xuser
Surname           :
UserPrincipalName :
```

For some reason, that information shows $null.

One thing I noticed is that when I typed:

```
PS> $user = Get-ADUser Xuser
```

It doesn't gather PasswordLastSet and LastLogonDate by default--you have to request that specific information as parameters with the `-Properties` switch.

If I type:

```
PS> $user.LastLogonDate
PS> $user
```

It now has the LastLogonDate field but it is $null. Same goes if I type:

```
PS> $user.PasswordLastSet
PS> $user
```

Both PasswordLastSet and LastLogonDate show in the output for `$user` but if I run a condition to see if the value is $null, it returns `True`.

Kind of squirrely behavior and I was curious as to why it does that. My best educated guess would be that $user is only populated with the default information from the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet and it is very simply WYSIWYG. To obtain those particular fields, I have to implicitly request them.

I wanted to see if certain fields were hidden by default (unless requested in the initial `Get-ADUser` cmdlet), so, I typed:

```
PS> $user.random
PS> $user
```

And sure enough, `random :` was a field in there.

I could even go as far as to do this:

```
PS> $user.random = "Property"
```

It shows `random : {Property}` when I type `$user`

**Question: Can anyone explain briefly why it behaves this way?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell function ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName not using alias parameter name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928911/powershell-function-valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-not-using-alias-parameter-na)

Comment: This is a peculiarity of the AD cmdlets, and it's explained pretty well in the linked duplicate. Basically, any property will behave as though it exists (with a `$null` value) instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: In addition to what @briantist said, `PasswordLastSet` and `LastLogonDate` are *not* part of the default attribute set for `ADUser` objects, so you explicitly have to request them with `-Properties`, as you've found

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test if a variable has content instead of just being present try:

```
$user.LastLogonDate.Length -gt 0
```